# How to style nested component in React Native with Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nested, styled-components, composition

How to change the style of the nesting component when declaring the parent style? eg. complex composition, in the case of React Native and Styled components.

P.S. I don't want to use ThemeProvider for each composed component.

I tried the official way I saw in Styled Components docs but it doesn't work. Perhaps because of non-exist css `cascading` in the case of react native.

So the question is: what is the proper way to do it right?

```
const StyledText = styled(Text)`
  color: blue;
`

const ComposedView= () => <View><StyledText>Hi</StyledText ></View>;

const StyledView = styled(ComposedView)`
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 120px;
  ${StyledText} {
    color: red;
  }
`

Expected Behavior
<StyledText> within <StyledView> should be red, and blue when it's outside a <StyledView
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you really keen on using this package? It seems like it's fighting against the spirit of react-native... My honest advice would be to use react native styling syntax!

Comment: Hi James! It looks like you are right. After struggling with it more than 2 days I decided to wrote my own styles HOC based on the standard react-native styles flow. But I'm not sure why the styled components works really hard in the case of complex react-native composition. Maybe we just don't know something.